# Ruby on Rails - how to render as xml models with has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, rendering

I have a ruby on rails application which has two models - ltests and sub_tests.
An ltest has a '`has_many`' association with sub_tests.
In the show method for ltests is as follows.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @ltest }
end
```

This renders the ltest object. However the sub_tests belonging to the ltest don't render.

How can I do this?

```
<ltest>
....
   <sub_test>
   ...
   </sub_test>
   <sub_test>
   ...
   </sub_test>
</ltest>
```

I tried rendering it using a view like this:

But this generates two xml documents rather than one with sub_tests embedded in ltests.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 14):

You don't have to use builder or erb for this. You can get what you want in the controller (at least I can in rails 2.3.4) like this:

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @ltest.to_xml(:include => :sub_tests) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems, rails can handle multiple levels of nesting. This is the code that I ended up with.

```
<%= @ltest.to_xml(:include => {
        :test_group => { :include => [ :user ]},
        :sub_tests => { :include => {
            :attachments => {},
            :errors => {},
            :test_bugs => {},
        } },
        :attachments => {},
        :errors => {},
        :test_bugs => {},
        :test_nodes => { :include => {
            :node => { :include => [ :networks ]},
            :attachments => {},
        }}
    } ) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

To render deep-nested objects:

```
render :xml => @record.to_xml(:include => {:groups => {:include => {:questions => {:include => :items}}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in the view `show.xml.erb` did the trick.

```
<%= @ltest.to_xml :include => [ :sub_tests ]%>
```

However, the objects nested inside sub_tests (test_logs, errors) get left out.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use xml builder to do this. http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/01/04/creating-xml-with-ruby-and-builder.html